# Symfony2 Controller is not callable

Tags: symfony

I've got this error:

> Controller
>   "Superplanner\UserBundle\Controller\RestController::afterResetAction"
>   for URI "/afterreset" is not callable.

routing:

```
after_reset:
    defaults: { _controller: "UserBundle:Rest:afterReset" }
    path : /afterreset
```

security:

```
- { path: ^/afterreset, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

method from RestController.php (from my UserBundle):

```
public function afterResetAction(Request $request)
{
    return new JsonResponse(array('Success' => 200, 'Response' => 'ok'), 200);
}
```

What is wrong with that?!

P.S. Yes, I've cleared cache

Comment: And if you try with `options:
        expose: true` in your routing file after path ?

Comment: What's the path to your controller? What's the defined namespace in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try, using the method without that Request parameter?

```
public function afterResetAction()
{
    return new JsonResponse(array('Success' => 200, 'Response' => 'ok'), 200);
}
```

If you want to get the request from inside the controller, you can do this:

```
$request = $this->get('request');
```